# Edit PDF files dynamically from Flash or Flex

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, pdf, air

I am planning to do a CD-ROM in either Flash or Flex, possibly using the Adobe AIR runtime.

This CD interactive will have a bunch of forms on it for the user to fill out. After they fill in a form, they will have the option of saving or printing a PDF that is based on there information.

I am trying to find a way of editing the content of the PDF in Flash, so when the user fills out the form, the application will fill in the PDF with there details from the form fields. Is this is possible?

It would be great if there was some way of having template PDFs (either on the CD as there own files, or in a Flash library), then flash could come along and fill in the specific fields inside the PDF.

Can Adobe AIR help me in any way here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know there is no direct way to edit existing pdf files in flex/air...

But there is a library to create pdf files http://alivepdf.bytearray.org/

Comment: Have tryed for a while to find this, but so far found nothing!